# Speed up MySQL Wordpress query

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I run the following query to find the current Wordpress user's last 3 comments. The query takes an unbelievable 0.95s to run while most of the other queries run in 0.005s. How can I speed up my query?

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_comments 
WHERE comment_approved = '1'
AND user_id = 5 
ORDER BY comment_date_gmt DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Remove the inverted commas, name the columns you actually want returned, and then provide the EXPLAIN

Comment: When you compared to other query in the sense, Is that same like searching comments or searching post? because normally searching comment is different than searching post.

Comment: Put a composed index on `(comment_approved ,user_id ,comment_date_gmt)`

Comment: Do you have proper indexes?